# Odoo Custom Tree Control

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

If you create new quotation in the `Sales` module, there are some control buttons:

- Add a product
- Add a section
- Add a note

[image]

I want to create those custom control for my tree view. But when I search from the source code, I can't find where is the python method is called.

```
...
<tree string="Sales Order Lines" editable="bottom">
    <control>
        <create name="add_product_control" string="Add a product"/>
        <create name="add_section_control" string="Add a section" context="{'default_display_type': 'line_section'}"/>
        <create name="add_note_control" string="Add a note" context="{'default_display_type': 'line_note'}"/>
    </control>
...
```

I search the `add_product_control` keyword, but there is nothing I found.

Answer (score 1):

Because odoo is not calling any python method it will trigger from javascript side and it will add new record and hide other fields using display_type
**display-types**

1. line_section
2. line_note

and you can find code in
/addons/account/static/src/js/section_and_note_fields_backend.js